# YamlDriver for Doctrine2 in Zend2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, yaml

I'm using the [DoctrineORMModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/) to integrate Doctrine2 with Zend2. Everything works just fine when I'm using the AnnotationDriver as described in various examples. However, I cannot get the YamlDriver to work. In my module.config.php I tried:

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        'ApplicationDriver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Application/Entity')
        ), 
        'YamlDriver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'extension' => '.dcm.yml',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Application/Mapping')
        ),

        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                'Application\Entity' => 'ApplicationDriver',
                'Application\Mapping' => 'YamlDriver'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

However, the EntityManager cannot find my classes. Cam you give me a working example of how to use yaml with doctrine2 and zend2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your entities are in namespace `Application\Entity`: this means your driver should be assigned for that namespace as in following example:

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        'MyYamlDriver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'extension' => '.dcm.yml',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/mappings')
        ),

        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                'Application\Entity' => 'MyYamlDriver',
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Basically, the configuration maps a particular named driver to a namespace that you want to use. In this case, `MyYamlDriver` is assigned to handle any mapping for the namespace `Application\Entity`

Comment: Just to be sure, I have to use entity classes regardless of the driver. Yaml is only a replacement for the annotations, not for the whole class with getters and setters?

Comment: Mappings are just decorators for your POPO (Plain Old PHP Objects). The driver is just a way of getting those mappings: it won't affect behavior of your classes in any way. Mappings only affect how the `ObjectManager` handles your persistence of the POPO